# Manipulate CSS from TypeScript in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm working with Angular and have a calendar which is filled dynamically. Also I have a range of dates and I want to change the background for several days within this range. I'm using moment for handeling dates and moment-range for the date-range.

In TypeScript I have managed to check if a specific day is in the range.

```
const a = new Date(2023,0,8);
const start = new Date(2023, 0, 9);
const end   = new Date(2023, 4, 23);
const range = moment.range(start, end);
console.log(range.contains(a));
```

But in the html I have only one 'day' which changes constantly. I have a css-class `class="background"` which changes my background when I write it in html but I can't access the specific days.
How can I only highlight the days which are in the range?

ts file

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  week: any = [
    "Mo",
    "Tu",
    "We",
    "Th",
    "Fr",
    "Sa",
    "Su"
  ];

  monthSelect: any[] | undefined;
  dateSelect: any;
  title: string | undefined;
  range: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDaysFromDate(1, 2023)
  }

  getDaysFromDate(month: number, year: number) {
    const startDate = moment(`${year}/${month}/01`)
    const endDate = startDate.clone().endOf('month')
    this.dateSelect = startDate;
    const diffDays = endDate.diff(startDate, 'days', true)
    const numberDays = Math.round(diffDays);
    this.monthSelect = Object.keys([...Array(numberDays)]).map((a: any) => {
      a = parseInt(a) + 1;
      const dayObject = moment(`${year}-${month}-${a}`);
      return {
        name: dayObject.format("dddd"),
        value: a,
        indexWeek: dayObject.isoWeekday()
      };
    });
  }

  changeMonth(flag: number) {
    if (flag < 0) {
      const prevDate = this.dateSelect.clone().subtract(1, "month");
      this.getDaysFromDate(prevDate.format("MM"), prevDate.format("YYYY"));
    } else {
      const nextDate = this.dateSelect.clone().add(1, "month");
      this.getDaysFromDate(nextDate.format("MM"), nextDate.format("YYYY"));
    }
  }
```

html file

```
<div class="wrapper-calendar">
  <div class="header-calendar">
    <div>
      <button (click)="changeMonth(-1)" class="btn-prev"><img src="back.png" alt="back"></button>
    </div>
    <h1>{{dateSelect | date:'MMMM yyyy'}}</h1>
    <div>
      <button (click)="changeMonth(1)" class="btn-next"><img src="forward.png" alt="forward"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol>
    <li *ngFor="let day of week" class="day-name">{{day | slice:0:3}}</li>

    <li  [style.gridColumnStart]="first ? day?.indexWeek : 'auto'"
        *ngFor="let day of monthSelect; let first = first">
      <span> {{day?.value}}</span>
    </li>



  </ol>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution will be to add additional property to the `day` entires, something like the following

```
...
 getDaysFromDate(month: number, year: number) {
    ...
    
    this.monthSelect = Object.keys([...Array(numberDays)]).map((a: any) => {
      a = parseInt(a) + 1;
      const dayObject = moment(`${year}-${month}-${a}`);
      return {
        name: dayObject.format("dddd"),
        value: a,
        indexWeek: dayObject.isoWeekday(),
        selected: someFunctionThatReturnsBooleanBasedOnTheSelectionRange(a)
      };
    });
  }
...
```

The `someFunctionThatReturnsBooleanBasedOnTheSelectionRange` should determine if the day is in the selected range, latter in the HTML you should add the following

```
  <li  [style.gridColumnStart]="first ? day?.indexWeek : 'auto'"
       [ngClass]="{'selected-day-backround': day.selected}"
        *ngFor="let day of monthSelect; let first = first">
      <span> {{day?.value}}</span>
    </li>
```

By using the ngClass directive you can add the custom background only to HTML elements that are part of the range.